# Python 3.3: Catching HTTPError with Timer

Tags: python

I've been trying to study python and I wanted to try catching a server time out error (in case my internet connection is interrupted or something) and adding a timer that will make the process stop for X seconds (in my code below it is 2 seconds) then try to continue the process again. Although I believe my logic is right (please do correct me if I'm wrong), I get an error that says

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 639, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 825, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I do not quite understand why my timer seems to trigger and error. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from threading import Timer

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.nowebsitecontainsthisaddress.com')

def ServerTimeOut(e):
    timer_rest = Timer(2.0, print('Time Out Error:'))
    timer_rest.start()
    print (e.reason)

    while timer_rest.is_alive():
        pass


while True:

    try:
        url = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        break
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        ServerTimeOut(e)
        req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.google.com')
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        ServerTimeOut(e)
        req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.google.com')
```

OS Used is windows7

Update:
Hi Guys, I tried tweaking my code into this and no more error is return. I do hope someone could enligthen me as to why the error was raised.. Thanks ^^,

```
import urllib.request
from threading import Timer

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.nowebsitecontainsthisaddress.com')

def printMessage():
    print('Time Out Error:')

def ServerTimeOut(e):
    timer_rest = Timer(2.0, printMessage)
    timer_rest.start()

    print (e.reason)

    while timer_rest.is_alive():
        pass

while True:

    try:
        url = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        break
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        ServerTimeOut(e)
        req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.google.com')
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        ServerTimeOut(e)
        req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the print function when the Timer is constructed. The correct way to construct your Timer is `Timer(2.0, print, 'Time Out Error')`.

Comment: Thank you. I probably should read more regarding threading. Although I wonder why the output is something like this: `'T i m e   O u t   E r r o r :'`